# Why does the following React code cause css highlights to skip when the css transaction is not over

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

The following React code should highlight the component when the children have changed. This highlighting does not always happen when the change happens before the css transaction of the previous change has finished. What can I do about it? Does it have to do with React? Or is it how css works?

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  highlight: {
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  },
  transparent: {
    transition: "background-color 5s linear",
  },
});

const ChangeHighlight = ({ children }: any) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [className, setClassName] = useState(classes.transparent);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setClassName(classes.highlight);
  }, [children]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (className === classes.highlight) {
      setClassName(classes.transparent);
    }
  });
  return <Box className={className}>{children}</Box>;
};

export default ChangeHighlight;
```

Comment: I test code, its work: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-bush-kgj3y?file=/src/App.js

the highloght its keep update until its end or not...may you have an issue in re-redner trigger it self for the component

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad : Thank you for your quick reply. I will try to reproduce it there too then. I have no idea why the transition duration matters on my setup.

Comment: You are welcome, If you can check where you call your component or share code here may I can help...thank you